# Sort a two-dimensional array of teachers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to do a program with a method that receives a two dimensional 3*3 array with the information of several Professors (created in a class called "Profesor". The information includes their ID, name, last name, age, sex, amount of hours worked and how much they win per hour, in that specific order set by the constructor), and sort them by their age and their daily salary in two separate methods. Their information is provided through the constructor. Also, their daily salary is calculated with a Salary() method (in the "Profesor" class), which returns the amount of hours times the amount they make per hours. 
Here's my code so far:

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Profesor arreglo[][];
    arreglo = new Profesor[3][3];

    Profesor profe1 = new Profesor(126509404, "Edgar", "Hernandez", 28, "M", 8, 0);
    profe1.setMoneyPerHour(1.66);
    Profesor profe2 = new Profesor(233849920, "Nuria", "Ramírez", 52, "F", 4, 0);
    profe2.setMoneyPerHour(2.43);
    Profesor profe3 = new Profesor(126509404, "José", "Hernandez", 29, "M", 8, 0);
    profe3.setMoneyPerHour(1.84);
    Profesor profe4 = new Profesor(126509404, "Arlene", "Hernandez", 34, "F", 6, 0);
    profe4.setMoneyPerHour(2.00);
    Profesor profe5 = new Profesor(126509404, "Orlando", "Hernandez", 36, "M", 10, 0);
    profe5.setMoneyPerHour(1.66);
    Profesor profe6 = new Profesor(126509404, "Ximena", "Hernandez", 55, "F", 4, 0);
    profe6.setMoneyPerHour(2.30);
    Profesor profe7 = new Profesor(126509404, "Eduardo", "Hernandez", 44, "M", 8, 0);
    profe7.setMoneyPerHour(1.66);
    Profesor profe8 = new Profesor(126509404, "Johanna", "Hernandez", 35, "F", 8, 0);
    profe8.setMoneyPerHour(1.66);
    Profesor profe9 = new Profesor(126509404, "Gilberto", "Hernandez", 42, "M", 8, 0);
    profe9.setMoneyPerHour(1.66);


    arreglo[0][0] = profe1;
    arreglo[0][1] = profe2;
    arreglo[0][2] = profe3;

    arreglo[1][0] = profe4;
    arreglo[1][1] = profe5;
    arreglo[1][2] = profe6;

    arreglo[2][0] = profe7;
    arreglo[2][1] = profe8;
    arreglo[2][2] = profe9;
```

The method to calculate the salary is as follows:

```
public double salary(){
    double salary = hours*moneyPerHour;
    return salary;
}
```

This is what I've tried so far to sort the array, according to what we've been teached in class:

```
public static void ordenaProfes(Profesor matrix[][]) {
  int ix = 0;
  int jx = 0;
  double minorSalary= matriz[0][0].salary();
  int n = matrix.length;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
          double aux= matrix[i][i].salary();
          if(aux  < minorSalary){
              ix = i;
              jx = j;
              minorSalary = aux;
          }
      }
  }
```

But using this won't work. It doesn't sort the array, only returning the salary at arreglo[0][0].

Comment: So... What have you tried?

Comment: What is the actual question? How to sort an array?

Comment: Why is this a two dimensional array? Make it one dimensional and sort normally.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why the part in which I explain what I've tried was not posted. 
@AnubianNoob We're practicing two-dimensional arrays, so I can't use a one dimension array.

Comment: How are you supposed to sort a 2D array? Can you explain that?

Comment: I posted the method we usually use to do that, but it's not working for this.

Comment: do you have to sort the second dimension of each array separately or how would you compare different sub-arrays?

Comment: your function `ordenaProfes` is not sorting the arrays, it is searching the element with lowest salary, nothing else

Comment: @JohnnyAW I was not explicitly asked to sort them separately. Just to order the array using the salary, from small to large. What I typed before is sort of what I've usually used to order two dimensional arrays, but it's not working this time.

Comment: @JohnnyAW Yes, that's what I've been receiving. I'm not being able to figure out how to make it sort them.

Comment: ok, so you want to sort all elements of the two-dimensional array? but witch dimension has priority?

Comment: simpliest way would be to create a new one-dimensional array, copy the values, sort it, and copy the values back, but you probably not allowed to do this, right? What kind of sorting algorithms do you know? Bubble-sort? quick-sort? merge sort? insert-sort?

Comment: Correct. So far, we've studied the Bubble Sort. We've used it several times with one dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, here is the bubble sort:

```
public static void ordenaProfes(Profesor matrix[][]) {
  int n = matrix.length;
  boolean changed = true; //need to check, if something have changed
  while(changed){
      changed = false; //set changed to false at the begining
      int ix = 0;
      int jx = 0;
      double lastSalary= matrix[0][0].salary(); //
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
              double aux= matrix[i][j].salary();
              if(aux  < lastSalary){
                  changed = true; //set change to true, so you know, that you have to iterate 1 more timr
                  //swap the element
                  Professor temp = matrix[ix][jx];
                  matrix[ix][jx] = matrix[i][j];
                  matrix[i][j] = temp;
              }
              //save the last element
              ix = i;
              jx = j;
              lastSalary = aux;
          }
      }
  }
```

ok, try it, i didn't test the code, so i hope i didn't forget something

EDIT: swap improved

EDIT2: moved variable initialization into while-loop

Comment: So far, it appears to be working. Now I'll just need to print the array. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, actually now I've tried several times and apparently it never stops looping. I'll check and see if I can change anything and let you know.

Comment: you are right, the problem was, i forgot to reinitialize the variables in the while-loop, it should work now

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, but forgot to post it back. Thanks a lot for all your help.